# How can i fire popstate event here?

Tags: javascript, pushstate, popstate

Most of the codes are very hard to understand.I make this pushstate working but dont know how to fire popstate.. Can anyone tell me how to fire popstate event here?

```js
function push(PUSH) {
  history.pushState(null, null, "/state=" + PUSH);
}




function clickMe(a) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

    document.getElementById('con' + i).classList.remove('active');




  }
  push(a);
  document.getElementById('con' + a).classList.add('active');



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't trigger that event. You use history back or forward.
[See reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event).

Window: popstate event. The popstate event of the Window interface is fired when the active history entry changes. ... The popstate event will be triggered by doing a browser action such as a click on the back or forward button (or calling history.back() or history.forward() in JavaScript).